# Not able to clamp camera's rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, gameobject, clamp

So I have this code in my `LateUpdate` function attached to my camera gameObject. I'm trying to rotate around a unity default cube as if it was an orbit. I have got the motion right but I'm not able to clamp the value... Here's the code.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    mInitialPosition = Input.mousePosition.x;
}

if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
{
    mChangedPosition = Input.mousePosition.x;
    float difference = mChangedPosition - mInitialPosition;
    if (mChangedPosition < mInitialPosition || mChangedPosition > mInitialPosition)
    {
        Rotation(-difference);
    }
}

private void Rotation(float inDifference)
{
   if (transform.eulerAngles.y < 60f  && transform.eulerAngles.y > -60f)
   {
       transform.RotateAround(mTargetToRotateAround.position, transform.up, inDifference * Time.deltaTime);
   }
}
```

Im tried to clamp the value this way as mathf.clamp dint seem to work out for me... So here i am  telling it to do the rotation function responsible for the rotation to happen only when camera-y rotation is below 60f and above -60f. But the rotation behaves super weird and i am super confused. So I did a bit of research on what value does the camera transform show outside in inspector window. Then i realized it was euler angles and not quaternion. Now i changed my code to euler but when i debug.log the value of `camera.transform.eulerangles.y` the value goes from 0 to 360. But in inspector the y value when reaching less than 0 starts printing -1 and so but in debug it shows 360,359 and so on.

1. **How to get the exact rotation value that there printed in inspector so I can clamp my camera accordingly?**
2. **Or is there any way to clamp my camera dont want it to go more that 60 degrees on both left and right!**

Comment: btw dont use Time.deltaTime here because if you do then the faster your device renders the more distance you have to move your mouse to turn the camera.

Comment: Also, try looking at `transform.localEulerAngles` and clamping between 0 and 60 or 300 and 360, or could do `angle = Mathf.Repeat(angle + 180f, 360f) - 180f;` to convert from [0,360) to [-180,180)  then you could clamp between -60 and 60.

Comment: [This](https://answers.unity.com/questions/438836/limit-camera-rotation-with-rotatearound.html) might also help.

Comment: @DevConcepts Thanks.... This helped me a lot and help me to solve my issue.... Big Thanks <3

Comment: @Ruzihm Thanks man... you made me learn a new thing and your comment helped me a lot

Comment: Glad it helped :)